# How to change data through select input in d3 chart in svelte?

Tags: d3.js, svelte

I'm trying to change the data to update the plot. I can do this manually by changing the `.data()` with `data1` or `data2`. But I would like to do this by using select input. I added the select input but I am unsure about how to bind it. I'm also not sure if I am on the right track. Please see this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/193cf8c8afa2496f8290bad188acf065?version=3.49.0).

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
    var data1 = [30, 86, 168, 281, 303, 365];
    var data2 = [281,303, 86, 168, 365]
    let el;
        let selected = 'data1';
    let options = [
        'data1',
        'data2'
    ]


    onMount(() => {
        d3.select(el)
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(data1)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .style("width", function(d) {
                return d + "px";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .chart :global(div) {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
    }
</style>


<select bind:value={selected}>
    {#each options as value}<option {value}>{value}</option>{/each}
</select>

<h3>
    {selected}
</h3>

<div bind:this={el} class="chart"></div>

<div bind:this={selected} class="chart"></div>
```

[image: example bar chart]

[Link to REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/193cf8c8afa2496f8290bad188acf065?version=3.49.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reactive statement to do this:

```js
$: selected === 'data1' ? setData (data1) : setData (data2)
```

EDIT:
Adding Functioning REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/02c579e1d3c54fe584f4ced130ddbf06?version=3.49.0

Comment: Where do I add it?

Comment: You'll need to create a "setData" function. You can add the reactive statement above the onMount function.

Comment: this reloads the whole chart though and you can't make use of the `update pattern` and transitions that d3 provides?